# Get list of Albums facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

Using c# or vb.net how can Obtain a list of album IDs?

I can get the `JSONObject` but don't know how to extract the IDs.

This is as far as I get in **VB**:

```
 Dim fbApp = New FacebookClient(accessToken.Text)
 Dim albums = DirectCast(fbApp.[Get]("me/albums"), IDictionary(Of String, Object))
```

How can i get just albums IDs into a new array?

Answer (score 1):

I am not into VB so you can do something in c# you got to figure way via VB yourself.

This works in c#

```
//Get the album data
dynamic albums = app.Get("me/albums");
foreach(dynamic albumInfo in albums.data)
{
   //Get the Pictures inside the album this gives JASON objects list that has photo attributes 
   // described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/
   dynamic albumsPhotos = app.Get(albumInfo.id +"/photos");
}
```

Comment: What can I get AccessToken ? **var app = new FacebookClient(accessToken.Text);**